# How to change ggplot2 layer hardcoded parameters after plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

As an example

```
library(ggfortify)
p <- autoplot(lm(rnorm(10)~ rnorm(10)))
p[[1]]
```

I can't work out how to change the point colour.

If the point colour had been mapped as an aesthetic I think

```
p[[1]] + scale_colour_manual(values = 'red')
```

might have worked. But as the colour was not mapped, I can't see how to do it without extracting the data and rebuilding the plot from scratch.

I'm actually asking because a package I am building creates some fairly complex plots with `autoplot`. I'm hoping for it to be easy to change any aspect of the plots after the fact. Therefore building from scratch, or any complicated work around is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is a good idea; if you want to do this, a better solution would be to fork ggfortify and edit the `autoplot.lm*` function.

Still, you could edit the geom_point, or more precisely replace it. I don't know of a way to change just one parameter to an existing layer.

```
library(ggfortify)
p <- autoplot.lm(lm(rnorm(10)~ rnorm(10)), )
```

Let's take a look at p with `str(p[[1]])`; it seems to be the first layer (check `p[[1]]$layers`), and it has the default values for geom_point,

```
p[[1]]$layers[[1]]
#geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#position_identity
```

Now, let us replace it with a new geom_point, specifying the points color:

```
p[[1]]$layers[[1]] <- geom_point(color = "red")
p[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, imgur refuses to upload the png file; feel free to add your own

Comment: Ah excellent. I didn't work out the ` <- geom_point(color = "red")` bit.

Comment: With regards to it not being a good idea and forking, the point is I don't know how users of my package will want to change the plots. So if I document this properly, they can change whatever they want.

Comment: see my edit about the replacement ; the point of a package is to help the user **not to** have to go deep in how things work... I think it is better to first try to work out what kind of changes your user may want to make and implement those (and if they need more, they will ask you for it), rather than tell them about low-level ggplot.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Think it clears something up actually. That if the default was geom_line(colour = 'red', linetype = 2), replacing it with geom_line(colour = 'blue') will then end up with the default linetype.

Comment: And I'm still not totally convinced about the design ideas. There's two issues. 1) it's "here's a whole extra bunch of arguments to learn" vs "you already know how to use ggplot2, just do that." (sort of). Also in my experience, with the best intentions, it's very hard to know what users might want to change, especially with graphics. Unless you assume they might change everything, and then you have 30 arguments. I've hit brick walls with plots using base graphics many times.

Comment: That said, I am adding arguments for what I think the most common changes would be (like for example point colour).

Comment: I'd be happy to debate that further, but I don't think comments are an appropriate place to do this ; here's a chat room if you are interested: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137075/debating-ggplot-programming-strategies